# How to use a react hook in an arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I'm designing an application in react native for medical use case. The idea is to record some audio and to send it to a local server. Therefore, the ip adress is defined at runtime.

Previously, I used a global const as adress (code below).

```js
const url = 'http://192.168.43.56:5000/';

const checkIsServerOnline = async (): Promise<string> =>
  axios.get(url, {
    timeout: 5000,
  });
```

Now I would  like to retrieve the url from a redux (persistant) store before using the function. I tried something like that, but it didn't worked:

```js
function CheckIsServerOnline(): AxiosPromise {
  const { ipAdress } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.config
  );

  return axios.get(ipAdress, {
    timeout: 5000,
  });
}
```

The error message it returned:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Do you have any idea how I would be able to retrieve the value from the redux state ?

(Apologies for the begineer question)

Comment: *"but it didn't worked"* Didn't work **how**? What error do you get, or what unexpected result? Note that hooks can only be called from other hooks or from component functions (well, that's the easiest way to think of it, anyway).

Comment: Apologies for the missing information. It showed the error message added in original post in console at runtime. No GET request is done.

I've thought about making it a component function with an UseState() for having the IP, but I can't export function from the component ?

Apologies for the lack of precision / blurry terms, I'm still a begineer in react.

Comment: It's the problem I thought it was, you're trying to use a hook (`useSelector`) outside of a component function. You can't do that. I haven't used Redux yet, but you might be able to use [`getState`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate)...

Comment: Thank you ! In the end, I did use `const state = store.getState();`

Answer (score 0):

React hooks can be used ONLY inside of React components.

Since you are using Redux I think you should set up your URL call in the store initialization. Here's a link to redux docs about initializing state: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state

Once you have it in the redux state you will be able to retrieve it wherever you want thanks to `mapStateToProps` from redux.